# Identity Server 4 Auto Login after Registering a User

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, registration

I'm wondering if anyone knows how you can "login" a user after you register them with Identity Server 4?

In my current setup I have a registration wizard on my website (localhost:44300). During the wizard a user will enter a Username, Email and Password which I send to my IS4 server (localhost:44310) using an http post call. On the IS4 server I create the user and then calling _signManager.SignInAsync. I have also tried calling HttpContext.SignInAsync. Upon returning to my website the user will complete the registration wizard and then be sent to our dashboard. The problem is when the user is sent to the dashboard they are asked to log in. I assume this has to do with the fact that the client is not receiving any tokens/cookies.

So does anyone know how I might accomplish this? 
Note the closest question I found was this one but it has not been answered: [Identity Server 4 Auto Login After Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040553/identity-server-4-auto-login-after-registration)

Please let me know if something is quite clear on what I am trying to accomplish.

Thank you for your time.

Client Startup

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:44310/";
    options.ClientId = "Id";
    options.ClientSecret = "Secret";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;
    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/";
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("Identity");
});
```

Client Register

```
var disco = await Client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:44310/");
if (disco.IsError)
{
    throw new Exception(disco.Error);
}

var tokenResponse = await Client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
{
    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

    ClientId = "Id",
    ClientSecret = "Secret",
    Scope = "Identity"
});

if (tokenResponse.IsError)
{
    throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
}

var token = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
Client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    model.Username,
    model.Email,
    model.Password,
    Claims = new List<string> {"User"},
});
var response = await Client.PostAsync("Account/register", new StringContent(myContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Models.RegistrationResponse>();
```

IS4 Register

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegistrationRequest model)
{ 
    user = new IdentityUser()
    {
        UserName = model.Username,
        Email = model.Email,
    };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        var cliams = new List<Claim>();

        foreach (var claim in model.Claims)
        {
            cliams.Add(new Claim(claim, ""));
        }
        await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, cliams);

        await _signManager.SignInAsync(user, true);//I was originally just doing this

        //I tried copying what Account/Login does, which is the following lines
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName));

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName);
        ////////////////////////////

        return Ok(new RegistrationResponse()
        {
            Successful = true,
            UserId = user.Id,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your client is using client credential flow to acquire token , and post data to IDS side to create user with that token . No user sign in process in your client app .

Comment: The client should never get to know the user's credentials. You can use a local wizard (for client specific registration) but you should redirect to IdentityServer to finish the registration. With [SignInManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#examine-register) you can easily sign in the user (setting all required cookies) and redirect back to your client without having to login.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Sadly I don't have much control over the flow of our registration.  I was just tasked with updating our site to .net core and keep the look and feel of the site the same.

Ruard are you suggesting that I do the reg wizard and then at the end I redirect to IdentityServer to that it can reg/log the user in and redirect back to our main site?

Comment: Have you considered centralizing registrations on your identity server? It’ll be really hard trying to bind a session with IdentityServer4 without the user actually entering their credentials on an IdentityServer4 page. The only way you’d be able to get the necessary authentication cookies for the user is somehow getting the user to redirect to IdentityServer4 without them realizing. It’s possible to do if IdentityServer gave a unique encrypted payload from its registration response that the user could form post to an ID4 page, but a lot more thought has to go into security considerations

Comment: @Josh I didn't know you replied to my comment. If you would've used the at (@) symbol then I would've received an alert. To answer your question, yes. To be honest, I haven't tried, but theoretically it should work. You should be able to pass parameters to the IdentityServer registration process. After registration redirect to your own site. You may have to create a custom registration form for this client.